# New-MailboxSearch: Parameter cannot be found

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013

We're running Exchange 2013 and attempting to follow Microsoft's [example 3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/ediscovery/search-public-folders#example-3) for an eDiscovery search on Public Folders using the Exchange Management Shell:

```
New-MailboxSearch -Name "Contoso Litigation" -AllSourceMailboxes $true -AllPublicFolderSources $true -SearchQuery '"price list" AND "contoso"' -StartDate "01/01/2015" -TargetMailbox "Discovery Search Mailbox"
Start-MailboxSearch "Contoso Litigation"
```

The user executing the commands has been assigned the "Discovery Management" role in Exchange, as [required](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/policy-and-compliance/ediscovery/ediscovery#in-place-ediscovery-permissions). However, when the first command is executed, it just produces the following error:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'AllSourceMailboxes'.

The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/policy-and-compliance-content-search/new-mailboxsearch?view=exchange-ps) for the New-MailboxSearch command states that this parameter is valid for both Exchange 2013 and 2016. Additionally, executing `Get-Help New-MailboxSearch` spits out the following list of parameters:

> SYNTAX
>   New-MailboxSearch -Name <String> [-AllPublicFolderSources
>   <$true | $false>] **[-AllSourceMailboxes <$true | $false>]** [-Confirm
>   <SwitchParameter>] [-Description <String>] [-DomainController <Fqdn>]
>   [-EndDate <ExDateTime>] [-EstimateOnly <SwitchParameter>]
>   [-ExcludeDuplicateMessages <$true | $false>] [-Force
>   <SwitchParameter>] [-IncludeKeywordStatistics <SwitchParameter>]
>   [-IncludeUnsearchableItems <SwitchParameter>] [-InPlaceHoldEnabled
>   <$true | $false>] [-InPlaceHoldIdentity <String>] [-ItemHoldPeriod
>   <Unlimited>] [-Language <CultureInfo>] [-LogLevel <Suppress | Basic |
>   Full>] [-MessageTypes <KindKeyword[]>] [-PublicFolderSources
>   <PublicFolderIdParameter[]>] [-Recipients <String[]>] [-SearchQuery
>   <String>] [-Senders <String[]>] [-SourceMailboxes
>   <RecipientIdParameter[]>] [-StartDate <ExDateTime>]
>   [-StatusMailRecipients <RecipientIdParameter[]>] [-TargetMailbox
>   <MailboxIdParameter>] [-WhatIf <SwitchParameter>] [<CommonParameters>]

The same error also appears for the `-AllPublicFolderSources` parameter if the `-AllSourceMailboxes` is removed from the command.

Why are these clearly documented parameters not being accepted? What could be preventing this from working?

### Update

So I've been digging into the workings of powershell and learned that the command being executed locally is merely a small powershell function which "proxies" the command and parameters to the Exchange server via "implicit remoting" (the Exchange Management Shell basically connects to the server via `New-PSSession` and then does an `Import-PSSession`). The real cmdlet executes on the server and exists in a .NET binary.

Decompiling that binary reveals the following parameters in the NewMailboxSearch class:

```
private const string ParameterAllPublicFolderSources = "AllPublicFolderSources";
private const string ParameterAllSourceMailboxes = "AllSourceMailboxes";
private const string ParameterDescription = "Description";
private const string ParameterEstimateOnly = "EstimateOnly";
private const string ParameterExcludeDuplicateMessages = "ExcludeDuplicateMessages";
private const string ParameterForce = "Force";
private const string ParameterIncludeKeywordStatistics = "IncludeKeywordStatistics";
private const string ParameterIncludeRemoteAccounts = "IncludeRemoteAccounts";
private const string ParameterIncludeUnsearchableItems = "IncludeUnsearchableItems";
private const string ParameterInPlaceHoldEnabled = "InPlaceHoldEnabled";
private const string ParameterInPlaceHoldIdentity = "InPlaceHoldIdentity";
private const string ParameterItemHoldPeriod = "ItemHoldPeriod";
private const string ParameterLanguage = "Language";
private const string ParameterLogLevel = "LogLevel";
private const string ParameterManagedBy = "ManagedBy";
private const string ParameterMessageTypes = "MessageTypes";
private const string ParameterPublicFolderSources = "PublicFolderSources";
private const string ParameterRecipients = "Recipients";
private const string ParameterSearchQuery = "SearchQuery";
private const string ParameterSenders = "Senders";
private const string ParameterSourceMailboxes = "SourceMailboxes";
private const string ParameterStatusMailRecipients = "StatusMailRecipients";
private const string ParameterTargetMailbox = "TargetMailbox";
```

So, the cmdlet **should** accept the parameters which are failing.

However, executing `(Get-Command New-MailboxSearch).Definition` in the Exchange Management Shell dumps out the code for the local powershell function, and **that** only lists the following parameters:

```
param(
  ${Description},
  ${DomainController},
  ${EndDate},
  ${EstimateOnly},
  ${ExcludeDuplicateMessages},
  ${Force},
  ${IncludeKeywordStatistics},
  ${IncludeUnsearchableItems},
  ${InPlaceHoldEnabled},
  ${InPlaceHoldIdentity},
  ${ItemHoldPeriod},
  ${Language},
  ${LogLevel},
  ${MessageTypes},
  ${Name},
  ${Recipients},
  ${SearchQuery},
  ${Senders},
  ${SourceMailboxes},
  ${StartDate},
  ${StatusMailRecipients},
  ${TargetMailbox}
)
```

Therefore it seems like there's some issue with the remote session and how `Import-PSSession` interacts with it. Unfortunately I'm not expert enough to figure out why.

I tried adding the missing parameters to the local function but it made no difference, and you also can't just execute the real binary cmdlet on the server because you get this error:

> Unable to execute the task. Reason: The task can't identify the user
>   that is executing the task.

Apparently the cmdlet can **only** be used through a remote session.

Anyone have any further insight?

Comment: Try removing the parameter and retype it. If you copied it from a website it might be possible that you also copied an invisible utf8 char.

Comment: Other possible causes: The exchange powershell module that you are using is too old (exchange 2010 level), or another powershell module is loaded that has a cmdlet with the same name.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Retyping the parameters makes no difference unfortunately. The earliest version of Exchange installed on the server was Exchange 2013 CU8 (now running CU20) so I don't think it can be down to an old powershell module. We've also tried installing the Exchange 2013 Management Shell on another machine, and executing the command there produces exactly the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, yes, it seems to be a bug in Exchange 2013, but it works as expected in Exchange 2016.

Test in Exchange 2013 CU18:
[image]

Test in Exchange 2016 CU8:
[image]

Comment: Microsoft seems found this issue and had updated the document recently. Now  in official document, "AllSourceMailboxes " parameter shows only applies to Exchange 2016.